# Rails 4.1.9 renaming table error on through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, migration

Alright I had three tables users, groups, groups_users
I run a migration to rename groups_users to memberships

```
rename_table :groups_users, :memberships
```

Everything is working fine but this association

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :groups, through: memberships, class: "Group"
```

throws the following error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "groups_users" does not exist
```

I searched my entire project for a forgotten reference on the old name but nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Why the down vote I wonder? I'm going to fix that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`has_and_belongs_to_many` association hasn't `through` option, you should use `join_table` option.

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :groups, join_table: 'memberships'
```

Comment: Did you add corresponding changes to the Group model: `has_and_belongs_to_many :users, join_table: 'memberships'` ?

Comment: For some reason I read `joins` instead of `join_table` before. Now its working thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

From rails giudes: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many

> The simplest rule of thumb is that you should set up a has_many :through relationship if you need to work with the relationship model as an independent entity. If you don't need to do anything with the relationship model, it may be simpler to set up a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship (though you'll need to remember to create the joining table in the database).
>
> You should use has_many :through if you need validations, callbacks or extra attributes on the join model.

I guess your Memership model has more functionality than just a join model, so you should use `has_many :through` association.